# How to load a second key in a dictionary in HDF5Matrix?

Tags: python, keras, hdf5, h5py

I am trying to load an `.h5` file using this documentation [`HDF5Matrix`](https://keras.io/utils/#HDF5Matrix):

```
test_images = HDF5Matrix(train_path+train_file,'images')
```

but I am getting this error:

> KeyError: "Unable to open object (object 'images' doesn't exist)"

I know this is because I have to follow this `['train']['images']` syntaxis to call the second key in a dictionary.

Normaly I use this code to open `.h5` files:

```
with h5py.File(train_path+train_file, 'r') as hf:
      train_images = hf['train']['images'][:]
```

My question is: Is it possible to access this second key in order to use `HDF5Matrix`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it finally!

It is really easy, `h5` files have this structure:

```
file
  Group
    Dataset
```

So if we want to get the `Dataset` for `HDF5Matrix('path/file','dataset')`. We just need to call the `Group` first. It will be:

```
from keras.utils import HDF5Matrix

x_data = HDF5Matrix('path/file', 'group/dataset')
```